# Need 1 CSS Div Height to Equal 2 CSS Div Heights

Tags: html, css

I am creating a code for my web programming class. I'm having troubles having my DIV tags to line up. I'm needing them to be equal, and no matter what I do I can't get them to work. The .black and .grey are the same part, and I'm not sure how to make it so they are even.

.css

```
.main {
    background-color:#e3e2e2;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
    margin:93%;
    border-radius:20px;
    float:left;
    margin:20px;
}
.bg1 {
    background-color:#d2cdc8;
    border-top-left-radius:20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
    width:65%;
    float:left;
}

.bg2 {
    background-color:#a79f97;
    border-top-right-radius:20px;
    width:35%;
    float:right;
}

.bg3 {
    background-color:#a79f97;
    border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
    width:35%;
    float:right;
}

.black {
    background-color:#3e3831;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-align:center;
    width:92%;
    border-top-left-radius:20px;
    border-top-right-radius:20px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    color:#d6d3c6;
    font-family: TF2Build;
}

.grey {
    background-color:#514840;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-align:center;
    width:92%;
    border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
    float:right;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    color:#aba9a8;
}
```

.html

```
<div class="bg1">
    <div class="main">
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bg2">
    <div class="black">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bg3">
    <div class="grey">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/W4Xb3/1/

Comment: Could you make an image with the final shape you want?

Comment: Like this, but with the same height. http://i.imgur.com/swPh1zr.png

Comment: Your CSS has two classes .main and .bg1 which are not present in your HTML. Can you add them too or remove the styles?

Comment: Your fiddle has both the divs of the same height.

Comment: They are added, they just aren't showing up on SO for some reason. Heres the code. http://jsfiddle.net/W4Xb3/1/

Comment: Put an empty line after .html in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your HTML, wrapping it in a "table" div and display the children as tablecells. (dropping `.bg3`, since it isn't needed)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="bg1">
        <div class="main">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg2">
        <div class="black">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="grey">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.bg1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.bg2 {
    width:35%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

And the [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Xb3/5/).

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to include that part of the code on SO, I think I figured it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're fighting issues with borders/margins/padding modifying the height/width.  IE before v9 used border-box as default, all other browsers and new versions of IE use content-box.  The only time I'll admit IE made things easier:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Try border-box on everything then readjust your height/width values.